# Lazy Load for touch devices

Tags: jquery, plugins, scroll, touch, lazy-loading

I'm using the jQuery plugin Lazy Load (http://appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), and on touch devices it doesn't run as smoothly because of the script not initiating until scrolling stops (as noted on https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/issues/87). Is there any known workaround for applying a touch event to trigger the script in the same way?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and see the Reference URL work out for you!

http://javascriptquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/83
    if ( $grid.length > 0) {

```
    $grid.imagesLoaded( function() {

        $grid.delay(200).masonry({

            gutterWidth: 14,

            itemSelector: '.item',

            isAnimated: false,

            isFitWidth: true,

            columnWidth: 194,

            animationOptions: { duration: 400 }

        });



        $('.item img').lazyload({

            effect: 'fadeIn'

        });

    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,** for anyone using lazyload with masonry on touch devices, this works fine (jquery+modernizr required):

```
        var $container = $('#content');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.masonry({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                });
            if ( Modernizr.touch ) { 
                $('.item img').lazyload({
                    effect: 'fadeIn',
                    event: 'touchLoad'
                    });                 
                $('.item img').trigger('touchLoad');
            }
            else {
                $('.item img').lazyload({
                    effect: 'fadeIn',
                    event: 'scroll'
                    });  
                $('.item img').trigger('scroll');
            }               
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good lightweight jquery plugin - "imgr". Check here https://github.com/agaase/imgr.

The plugin is mobile optimised; so works great with touch devices. You can also load an image as a normal element or as a background image.

Check demos here

http://agaase.github.io/webpages/imgr/demos/demo1.html
http://agaase.github.io/webpages/imgr/demos/demo2.html